# Javascript creating a new line on the html page?

Tags: javascript, return

I have a javascript function that prints some textboxes when the user clicks a button.

However when the user clicks the buttons multiple times the textboxes just go along the page but I want it to always be on a new line every time the function is called.

I tried this

```
x=document.write ('<br/>');
           document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(x)
```

But that just clears my page to blank white.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById ('txtara').innerHTML += '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You did that wrong. `document.write` writes to the end of the page, and doesn't return an HTML element. What you need is this:

```
var x = document.createElement('br');
document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using document.write will clear everything else from the page. You should use CSS to style your text boxes so they appear as you want them to.